# GWT add tooltip to Tab

Tags: gwt, tabs, tooltip, tabbar, tabpanel

I am using GWT.

I have a TabPanel which has a TabBar with Tabs in it.  My issue is that there is no way that i can find to set the Tooltip for the individual Tabs.
I get the Tab i want using: `getMainTab().getTabBar().getTab(0)`.
There is no operation that allows me to get its header so that i can set its tooltip.
I have looked around but can't find anything useful.  I found a setTitle option but thats on the TabBar which is not correct as I need to be able to do it on a specific Tab.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass HTML to a tab header when you add a tab, and this HTML may include `title` attribute.

Comment: Can you give an example. i have the TabPanel object which doesnt give me any header options, neither does the TabBar or the Tab in question.

Comment: Both TabPanel and TabLayoutPanel have methods to add HTML to the header when adding a widget to the panel. http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/TabLayoutPanel.html

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try this:

```
// Create a tab bar
tabLayoutPanel = new TabLayoutPanel(100, Unit.PX);

// Create a panel
FlowPanel tabPanel = new FlowPanel();
// fill the tab with its contents ...

// Create HTML as tab for the panel
HTML htmlTab = new HTML("HTML-Tab");
htmlTab.setTitle("Tooltip for HTML");

// Add panel with its tab to the tabLayoutPanel
tablayoutPanel.add(tabPanel, htmlTab);
```

If you prefer an Image as tab, do it this way:

```
// Create an image as tab for the panel 
Image imageTab = new Image(... your image resoure ...);
imageTab.setTitle("Tooltip for Image");

// Add panel with its tab to the tabLayoutPanel
tablayoutPanel.add(tabPanel, imageTab);
```